# Story about a 100+ year old teacher who appears as a 9 year old child

Tags: story-identification

Searching for the title of a story about a teacher who is over 100 years old, but has the appearance of a 9 year old child.

The student is a genuine 9 year old and they live in an artificial environment mocked up to look like a Louisiana Bayou setting at the edge of a swamp. There’s a mention of a rusted out Toyota behind the shed.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 17):

This is John Varley's [Beatnik Bayou](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41622).

It has all the elements you describe of the artificial environment looking like a Louisiana swamp

> There are two structures on Beatnik Bayou. One is an old, rotting bait
> shop and lunch counter called the Sugar Shack, complete with a rusty
> gas pump out front, a battered Grapette machine on the porch, and a
> sign advertising Rainbow Bread on the screen door. There's a gray
> Dodge pickup sitting on concrete blocks to one side of the building,
> near a pile of rusted auto parts overgrown with weeds. The truck has
> no wheels. Beside it is a Toyota sedan with no windows or engine.
> A dirt road runs in front of the shack, going down to
> the dock. In the other direction the road curves around a
> cypress tree laden with moss--
>
> --and runs into the wall. A bit of a jolt. But though twelve
> acres is large for a privately owned disneyland, it's not big
> enough to sustain the illusion of really being there. "There"
> in this case is suppose to be Louisiana in 1951, old style.

and the teacher in a child's body.

> If I sounded hard on Cathy, I really shouldn't have been. He
> was a damn fine teacher. He was able to take those old saws
> about learning by doing, seeing is believing, one-on-one
> instruction, integration of life experience--all the
> conventional wisdom of the education establishment--and make it
> work better than any teacher I had ever seen.
>
> I knew he was a counterfeit child. I'd known that since I first
> met him when I was seven. [...] [He] was really forty-eight
> years old. Physically he was just my age, which is almost
> thirteen: a short: slightly chubby kid with curly blond hair and
> an androgynous face

Pages 151-152, from the collection [The Barbie Murders](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25557), September 1980 first printing.

Comment: Better timing than me. Well done. I've taken the liberty of adding a little to the quoted material to more explicitly hit several points. My copy is also in the collection *The Barbie Murders*.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about adding the teacher part but I got tired of holding the book open and typing....

Comment: I remembered this story when I read the question yesterday -- knew it was one of John Varley's Hotline universe stories, but couldn't recall the title or which collection.  Nice job.